# CakePHP: What should go in /Lib vs /Vendor vs /Plugin

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I've been using CakePHP for a while and I *still* don't really understand what should go in `/Lib` vs `/Plugin` vs `/Vendor`. I know that plugins are basically mini apps with their own controllers, etc. But there are many situations when all three seem like ok options. Could someone shed some light on this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24261432/how-to-use-common-function-in-helper-and-component-in-cakephp

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> **Lib**
>
> Contains 1st party libraries that do not come from 3rd parties or
>   external  vendors. This allows you to separate your organization’s
>   internal libraries from vendor libraries.
>
> **Plugin**
>
> Contains [plugin](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html) packages.
>
> **Vendor**
>
> Any third-party classes or libraries should be placed here.
>   Doing so makes them  easy to access using the App::import(‘vendor’,
>   ‘name’) function. Keen observers  will note that this seems redundant,
>   as there is also a vendors folder at the top level of our directory
>   structure. We’ll get into the differences between the two  when we
>   discuss managing multiple applications and more complex system setups.

Source: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-folder-structure.html

To clarify further, `Lib`is recommended for libraries that you write yourself. This may just be a few classes or entire libraries. `Vendor` is recommended for libraries or scripts that you may download from github for instance. `Plugin` is strictly for cakephp framework plugins.

Regarding `Lib` vs `Vendor` for you own scripts or 3rd party scripts there is no difference that I am aware of. I have put my own scripts in both as well as 3rd party scripts in both locations and it hasn't made any difference. It's just a recommended way to organize your files.

You can load your scripts from `Lib` or `Vendor` using `App::import()` which is the same as `require_once()`. To load framework files or your own scripts that follow cakephp conventions, you would use `App::uses()`. This uses the paths defined using `App::path()` or `App::build()` to find the files.

Comment: Thanks! I think the difference is much more clear. Would you mind also adding a few words about the implications of choosing /Lib vs /Vendor? For example, stuff in Vendor will be accessed with `App::import()` whereas Lib stuff seems to require `App::uses()` and some other configurations. I'm sure there's a good reason why they are implemented differently, but it is not obvious to me.

Comment: Not obvious at all. It seems superfluous to have both. Especially given accessing files in Lib and Vendor is completely different.